# Error Compiling with Generics and Workflow Activity Base Class

Tags: c#, generics

Anyone know why this won't compile?  The problem has to do with inheriting from the Workflow Activity.

```
public class MyActivityBase<T> : System.Workflow.ComponentModel.Activity
{
    public T MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Compile Error Message

```
Error   1   Could not create activity of type '...Activities.Common.MyActivityBase`1'. System.ArgumentException: Cannot create an instance of ...Activities.Common.MyActivityBase`1[T] because Type.**ContainsGenericParameters is true**.
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceCheckThis()
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Workflow.ComponentModel.Compiler.XomlCompilerHelper.InternalCompileFromDomBatch(String[] files, String[] codeFiles, WorkflowCompilerParameters parameters, WorkflowCompilerResults results, String localAssemblyPath)
```

Thanks,
T

Comment: Hello Thomas. I'd like to bring something to your attention. It's common practice to accept answers once acceptable answers are provided. You can accept an answer by going back to your previous questions and clicking the large check image left of the desired answer. The more answers you accept, the more likely people will want to answer your future questions. See the FAQ for more help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your type is being instantiated via Reflection. Whatever code is doing the instantiation doesn't know how to instantiate a type with Generic parameters. It therefore throws an Exception.

Unfortunately, there's really nothing you can do if you want to use `MyActivityBase<T>` directly. You might be able to get by using concrete child implementations of your base class though (something like `public class MyActivityString : MyActivityBase<string>`)